# style a div based on the condition that a separate table with no tds

Tags: html, css

I have a table and a div next to it.

```
 <table>
  <tbody>  
   <tr> 
     <th> 
         Name
     </th>
     <th>
         Age
     </th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 <table>

  <div>Table has not tds</div>
```

I wanted to highlight the div based on the condition that the above table has no tds.

I tried to do this:

```
table tbody td:empty + div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The above is not working. Can anyone suggest a solution with pure CSS?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible without `:matches()`.

Comment: How do you do it with :matches()?

Comment: I doubt `:matches()` would be able to solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` on the CSS selector does not work because the `<div>` is not a sibling of the `<td>`. On the other hand, `table + div { something: something }`would work, because they would be on the same hierarchical level.

Aside from that, unfortunately, AFAIK, there's no way to make a CSS rule where the child affects the parent (nor the siblings of the parent).

Basically, the HTML will need to be restructured in some way to do what you want. You could, for example, write a small bit of JS code that adds a class to the table if it has no `<td>`s, so that this class could be used by a CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a pure CSS solution to this, but you'll need to give your tables a `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` and then re-purpose the otherwise unutilised `tfoot` as your "indicator" `div`:

```css
table {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
margin-right: 148px;
height: calc(100% - 80px);
vertical-align:top;
}

thead, tbody, tr, th, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(191,191,191);
}

tfoot {
height: 80px;
}

tfoot td {
text-align: center;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
transform: translateX(152px);
padding: 2px;
border: 2px solid rgb(127,0,0);
}

tbody + tfoot td {
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
border: 2px solid rgb(0,63,0);
transform: translate(152px, -100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead> <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr><td>Table has no tbody</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>

<table>
<thead> <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Alice</td><td>01</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bob</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>Chuck</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dan</td><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td>Eve</td><td>101</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><td>Table has a tbody</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. But, I used angular's ng-class to check for the length of the array that was supposed to populate the table and based on the condition I changed the styles of the div. I thought the :empty pseudo class would provide a simple css only solution.

```
 <table>
  <tbody>  
   <tr> 
     <th> 
         Name
     </th>
     <th>
         Age
     </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 <table>

 <div ng-class="people.length < 1 ? 'highlight-div':''">
     Table has no tds
</div>
```

---

```
   .highlight-div {
     background: red;
   }
```